# Immutable types (especially collections) and covariance in java

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Suppose I have this class `WidgetHolder` that holds `Widget` instances. Internally, I back it up with a `List<Widget>`. I guarantee that it is immutable so after construction no widget is added to the holder.

`WidgetHolder` also exposes a `getWidgets()` operation that returns an immutable view of the widget list.

I would like to have a derived `SpecificWidgetHolder` class that holds `SpecificWidget` instances, and whose return type for `getWidgets()` is `Collection<SpecificWidget>`.

I have the same guarantee, i.e. the `SpecificWidgetHolder` constructor takes a collection of `SpecificWidget` instances and does not modify it in any way.

Given that both `WidgetHolder` and `SpecificWidgetHolder` are immutable, the usual objections that justify generic invariance do not seem to apply (?)

Is there a clean way of expressing this in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you apply a generic logic? Something like this `WidgetHolder<T extends Widget>` and `T getWidget()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario that you described is very common: You store a collection of objects internally, and want to expose a *read-only* version of this collection. This is often accomplished using the [`Collections#unmodifiableCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection-java.util.Collection-) method (and the specific ones for other collection types) :

```
class WidgetHolder {
    private final List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();

    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(widgets);
    }
}
```

---

But note that *if* the collection is unmodifiable anyhow, you can achieve the desired covariance by exploiting the fact that the collection is unmodifiable. When it is unmodifiable, you can declare the return type as

```
public List<? extends Widget> getWidgets() { ... }
```

This way, everybody will be able to use the list in the same way as before. He can read and iterate it. He can not add new elements, because it is unmodifiable - and a nice side-effect is that this unmodifiability is (to some extent) visible here **syntactically**:

```
List<Widget> widgets = widgetHolder.getWidgets();
widgets.add(new Widget()); // throws UnsupportedOperationException AT RUNTIME!
```

vs.

```
List<? extends Widget> widgets = widgetHolder.getWidgets();
widgets.add(new Widget()); // Does not compile!
```

(Note that calls like `widgets.remove(x)` or `widgets.add(null)` would still compile but throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` - it's only a subtle hint)

---

The key point, regarding your question, is that you can override this method with a more specific return type. **This is the real covariance here**.

So in a class `SpecificWidgetHolder` you have the choice between 3 ways of overriding this method:

1. Using the same type as in the superclass:

   ```
   public List<? extends Widget> getWidgets()
   ```
2. Using the specific type, of which you know that it is assignable to the type of the superclass:

   ```
   public List<SpecificWidget> getWidgets()
   ```
3. Using the the wildcard type again, leaving room for further specializations (like a `VerySpecificWidgetHolder`):

   ```
   public List<? extends SpecificWidget> getWidgets()
   ```

There are subtle differences of how the class may be used. Particularly, whether the information about the "specificness" is available to a caller. I tried to point this out in this example:

```
// With option 1, you only receive Widgets - even
// from a SpecificWidgetHolder
List<? extends Widget> widgets = specificWidgetHolder.getWidgets();
Widget widget = widgets.get(0);

// With option 3., you still know that a SpecificWidgetHolder
// provides a list of SpecificWidgets
List<? extends SpecificWidget> specificWidgets = specificWidgetHolder.getWidgets();
SpecificWidget specificWidget = specificWidgets.get(0);
```

Basically, you have to decide whether someone who has a `SpecificWidgetHolder` should be able to obtain the `SpecificWidget` instances from it or not.

---

<sub>A side note: As shown in another answer, this can be solved with generics as well. But I don't think that this is necessary here. And I'm usually a bit hesitant with attaching type parameters to classes, because they may be harder to understand and maintain than non-generic types. Generics (type parameters) are like salt: At the right place and the right dose they may make things simply *better*. But when you get carried away with them, and end up with nested generics and method signatures like `<S, T extends Number> Foo<S, ? super T> getFoo()`, this may hinder readabiliy and maintainability quite a lot</sub>

Comment: Thanks for that nice and detailed answer! But it would be interesting if you could explain how your unmodifiable list example does not compile. AFAICT `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns an instance of a class that implements the `List` interface, including `add` et al... ?

Comment: Just for my own reference, this is detailed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class WidgetHolder<T extends Widget>
{
  public List<T> getWidgets()
  {
    return (widgets);
  }

  private List<T> widgets;

} // class WidgetHolder

public class SpecificWidgetHolder extends WidgetHolder<SpecificWidget>
{
}
```

Comment: Well that was fast :)